# PHP Удаление субмассива из многомерного массива по условию

Tags: php, массивы

День добрый, всем!
Полдня мучаюсь уже с одной задачкой. Перепробовал и array_diff_assoc , map и filter
Есть многомерный массив.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 52
        [price] => 3000
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 36
        [price] => 3000
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 52
        [price] => 3500
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 36
        [price] => 3500
    )
)
```

необходимо сравнить подмассивы с одинаковым id по цене, оставить те, что с наименьшей ценой, а с наибольшей удалить.
после всех манипуляций на выходе будет

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 52
        [price] => 3000
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 36
        [price] => 3000
    )
)
```

Comment: приведите пример своих попыток решения

Comment: Из всех перечисленных функций, почему-то нет `array_reduce()` Рискнёте попробовать?  

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
// Исходный массив
$inputArray = array(
    array('id' => 52, 'price' => 3000),
    array('id' => 36, 'price' => 3000),
    array('id' => 52, 'price' => 3500),
    array('id' => 36, 'price' => 3500)
);

// Создаем временный массив для хранения результатов
$resultArray = array();

// Группируем элементы по полю "id"
$groupedArray = array();
foreach ($inputArray as $item) {
    $id = $item['id'];
    if (!isset($groupedArray[$id]) || $item['price'] < $groupedArray[$id]['price']) {
        $groupedArray[$id] = $item;
    }
}

// Преобразуем сгруппированный массив в итоговый результат
$resultArray = array_values($groupedArray);

// Выводим итоговый массив
print_r($resultArray);
```

Comment: Решение отлично работает, спасибо!